# Can you use the PHP date() with array items?

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have an array $creation_date[] that I am looping through. This contains MySQL timestamps. I want to change these timestamps into dates like `January 4, 1992`. I have this code: `date('F j, Y', $creation_date[$i])` (its in a while loop with `$i` incrementing it). It is returning an error at that line `A non well formed numeric value encountered`. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to use the strtotime() function.

date() assumes a unix timestamp (like time()) as a second argument, and the string coming from mysql is a string :)

Try date('F j, Y', strtotime($creation_date[$i]));

Comment: you may mark this post as "answered" if the solution fits you! :)

Answer (score 1):

not sure on that error but i think you need [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in there: `date('F j, Y', strtotime($creation_date[$i]))`

if that doesn't work, as you looping if you print the $creation_date[$i] does it print as expected?